# How did Charles Sanders Peirce react to his stigmatization?

Tags: biographical-details

Do we have any evidence on how Charles Sanders Peirce reacted to his stigmatization by various academics? By stigmatization, I mean denying him tenure at Johns Hopkins, leaving the house when they learned that he was staying for the night, etc.

Comment: Which Peirce are we talking about?

Comment: Charles Sanders Peirce. His father was well respected as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Pierce was a difficult man. A *Physics World* article implied that it's was his character that alienated him from his fellow academics: He was 'aloof', 'suspicious' and subject to 'fits of temper'.

There was nothing in the article about him being 'stigmatised'. If so, this might say much more about the culture and sociology of academia, and specifically that of the physical sciences than the man himself. After all, even Einstein was marginalised within the physics community, with even Freeman Dyson avoiding him after arranging a meeting with him ...